# using getelement by id instead of name

Tags: jquery

Been trying to see how flexible this is. http://jsfiddle.net/PJSha/4/ i have changed the get element from Name to ClassName which both worked but does not work when i try and achieve it with Id... is there a reason

Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<input type="text" id="foo" class="bar" name="domain">
<div onclick="check_domain_input()">Click</div>

<div id="dialog" title="Attention!" style="display:none">
    Please enter a domain name to search for.
</div>

<script>
    function check_domain_input()  {        
        var domain_val = document.getElementById('foo');

        if (domain_val[0].value.length > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsById` should be `getElementById` (no `s` after `Element`). It only ever returns a reference to one element, or `null`.

Because it returns a reference, not a `NodeList`, the `[0]` is not necessary when you access its `value` property.

Comment: So "s" works with "Name" and "className" but not with "Id". does this mean you can select more then one element when chosing a "name" or "class"?

Comment: @DavidWalter You'll need to apply what I wrote in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: can you run multiple items for classname and name?

Comment: With ids you should only have one element with a certain ID in a document - that's why there is no getElementsByID but only getElementByID. Now, there is nothing stopping you from reusing the id but the behaviour will depend entirely on the browser - see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really for details. You should use class to organize your elements in groups. Reusing the same name might get you into troubles on the server side: http://tinyurl.com/633dp99

Comment: sry not use the same name but use the same script for multi ids.

Answer (score 1):

`Id`s are used `explicitly` in a page your are using ids twice and its over riding try using different ids and let me know if it fixes or not.

```
<input type="text" id="foo" class="bar" name="domain">
<div id="foo" onclick="check_domain_input()">Click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is required that the element you are fetching should also be declared with the `id="foo"`

Please refer this link..a [practical example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_getelementbyid)

Comment: it is <input type="text" id="foo" class="bar" name="domain">
check http://jsfiddle.net/PJSha/4/

Answer (score 0):

Or pass this,

```
onclick="check_domain_input(this)"
```

and then get the id:

```
function check_domain_input(t) { alert(t.id); ...
```